# Show different scenes for different levels. AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using AndEngine for a Game 2d. Wanna to load different Activities or better different Scenes for the different levels and for the main menu. How to achieve this ? ..Where can I find an example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend for you to use scenes instead activities to avoid black screens between switching activities. Create your own scene manager and use it for changing screens.
Basic example:

```
public class SceneManager {
    private static Game game; // your main activity
    private static SceneManager sm;

    private Scene mScene;

    private SceneManager(){
    }

    public static void init(Game pGame){
            SceneManager.game = pGame;
    }

    public static SceneManager getManager(){
            if(game == null) throw new IllegalStateException("You must first initialize scenemanager class");
            if(sm == null) return sm = new SceneManager();

            return sm;
    }

    public void setMainMenuScreen(){
            mScene = new MainMenuScene();
            game.getEngine().setScene(mScene);
    }

    public void setGameScreen(){
            mScene = new GameScene();
            game.getEngine().setScene(mScene);
    }

    public Scene getCurrScene(){
            return mScene;
    }
}
```

And in your main class Game.java firstly you should initialize your scene manager class and get local instance. After this feel free to use it according your game logic:

```
private SceneManager sm;
SceneManager.init(this);
sm = SceneManager.getManager();
sm.setMainMenuScreen();

...

sm.setGameScreen();
```

Comment: what if third party apps are used? You cannot use scene manager there AndEngine activity is paused and when resume it black out again.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand your comment. Black screen after pause - it is AndEngine's problem, because it reloads resources again...

Comment: I was saying that we use scene manager to avoid black screen on Pause. But what if we are using third party apps in or game. We cannot handle them our selves? Is their any solution to avoid black screens there?

Comment: ok. I understood. I think it's not possible without implementing any hacks, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Using above method the heap memory of the device continuously increase because each time we are creating new object of the scene. When we use long time an activity it become overflow. So please provide any solution.