# Avoiding black screen when Activity resumes in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

Is there any way to avoid black screen when AndEngine activity is resumed?

Comment: try this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154251/show-different-scenes-for-different-levels-andengine

Comment: @MrWaqasAhmed formatted: [question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154251/show-different-scenes-for-different-levels-andengine) [question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154251/show-different-scenes-for-different-levels-andengine) (click "help" while writing a comment to see formatting rules)

Comment: I have followed the structure mentioned in that post. I am also using scene manager, but when it comes to third party apps it show black screen. Like I opened Papaya or Openfeint activity and when I cam back it was black out for a while what the solution for this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you overridden this method?

```
@Override
public void onGameCreated() {
    super.onGameCreated();
}
```

Calling "super.onGameCreated()" is important.